# preg_replace entire string if currently contains a string

Tags: php

i would like to replace the entire URL to completely new one if the URL currently contains an unwanted string.

this is what i tried.

```
if (preg_match('/(site1.com)/i')){
  $url = preg_replace('/(site1.com)/i',('http://www.site2.com/newsite/index.php?a=b'),$url);
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem necessary to do a `preg_replace` if you want to replace the *entire* string. So, try this:

```
$url = 'http://www.site1.com/';
$pattern = '/(site1.com)/i';
$newUrl = 'http://www.site2.com/newsite/index.php?a=b';

if (preg_match($pattern, $url)){
    $url = $newUrl;
}

print_r($url);
```